# Adding only existing words in a file from a another file and removing the rest (unix)?

Tags: text-processing

I have two texts (frequency count dic) I want to increase the frequency count of the first file by adding only the same word in the second file.

for example 
my file1

```
100  man 
522  women  
600  kids 
600  football
```

my file2

```
100 man 
300 women 
600 kids 
900 football
500 fifa 
500 world
```

I want this output

```
200 man
822 women 
1200 kids
1500 football
```

The words in the second file, that not exit in the first file will be remove.

```
500 fifa  # removed 
500 world # removed
```

I tried with sed/cat and join cmd but I'm not getting the result I want

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's an awk approach:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$2]=$1; next}($2 in a){print $1+a[$2],$2}' file1 file2
200 man
822 women
1200 kids
1500 football
```

If you also want to include words that appear in `file1` but not in `file2`, use:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$2]=$1; next}{print $1+a[$2],$2}' file2 file1
```